# error: unknown type name ‘bool’

Tags: c, gcc, lex

I downloaded the source code and wanted to compile the file of scanner.  It produces this error:

```
[meepo@localhost cs143-pp1]$ gcc -o lex.yy.o lex.yy.c -ll
In file included from scanner.l:15:0:
scanner.h:59:5: error: unknown type name ‘bool’
In file included from scanner.l:16:0:
utility.h:64:38: error: unknown type name ‘bool’
utility.h:74:1: error: unknown type name ‘bool’
In file included from scanner.l:17:0:
errors.h:16:18: fatal error: string: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

And I tried to use different complier to compile it, but it appeared different errors.

```
[meepo@localhost cs143-pp1]$ g++ -o scan lex.yy.c -ll
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ll
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My os is 3.0-ARCH, I don't know why this happened. How do I fix the error?

Comment: `#include <stdbool.h>`

Answer (score 238, accepted):

C90 does not support the boolean data type.

C99 does include it with this include:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
```

Comment: C99 does, if you have `#include <stdbool.h>`.

Comment: C99 has a native boolean type called `_Bool`. The `<stdbool.h>` header provides a typedef for it called `bool`, along with `true` and `false`.

Comment: how come I can compile my bool stuff fine on OSX without include stdbool.h ?

Comment: I've copy-pasted some "C" code as well and as answered had to include stbool.h so `gcc` compiled. However seems C++ knows booleans "out of the box" so I could simply use `g++` for compiling without any changes to the code. So depending on your context, source of code and further errors maybe you're not looking at c but c++ code.

Answer (score 70):

C99 does, if you have

```
#include <stdbool.h>
```

If the compiler does not support C99, you can define it yourself:

```
// file : myboolean.h
#ifndef MYBOOLEAN_H
#define MYBOOLEAN_H

#define false 0
#define true 1
typedef int bool; // or #define bool int

#endif
```

(but note that this definition changes [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) for `bool` type so linking against external libraries which were compiled with properly defined `bool` may cause hard-to-diagnose runtime errors).

Comment: My own favorite way to define `bool` is: `typedef enum { false, true } bool;`

Comment: You need the `typedef` to be able to refer to the type as `bool` rather than `enum bool`.

Comment: Thx, I learns a lot from you, and I have to apologize for my stupid question because I mix C and C++ which can reflect the weakness of my basic knowledge. Again, thank you for your patience!

Comment: The latter way is inherently risky because there is no implicit conversion . For example if we had 16-bit ints and `long FLAG = 0x4000000;  bool b = ( x & FLAG );` then this causes undefined behaviour (with the likely result that `b` will appear to be false even if `x` had the flag set).  This is harder to spot when the `bool` is a function parameter. Use, but use with care.

Comment: Beware! This `typedef` *won't* behave the same as a true C99 bool in edge cases, both because a true C99 bool has only two values but this `typedef` supports as many as `int` does, but also because C99 `bool` has special casting rules which the `typedef` does not. Example: in C99, `(bool)99999998430674944` is unambiguously `true`. With your `typedef`, compiling in GCC on my machine, `(bool)99999998430674944` is `false` (due to how overflow is handled when casting).

Comment: @KeithThompson Definition like this breaks ABI if you try to link with external library which was compiled with normal bool.

Comment: @yugr: Sure, I wouldn't expect a user-written typedef to match something defined in an API. If built-in `_Bool` / `bool` is available use it. The typedef is a reasonable approach if you want a boolean type and you're stuck with a pre-C99 compiler.

Comment: @KeithThompson Ah, makes sense. Could you clarify this in your answer? In my experience dealing with runtime bugs caused by ABI mismatches like this is _very_ painful. You have the "If the compiler does not support C99" part but I don't think everyone realizes the consequences of using this approach in normal x86 GCC.

Comment: @yugr: It shouldn't be an issue in practice. Calls to externally defined functions are going to require consistent declarations. If you pass a value of type `typedef bool ...` type to a function expecting `_Bool`, it's going to be implicitly converted. If it defines a pointer to `_Bool` or a `_Bool` member, it should be flagged by the compiler. (I see I mixed up "ABI" vs. "API"; I'm not quite sure what the implications of the distinction might be.)

Comment: @KeithThompson No, I'm talking about situation where external header uses `bool` as well. So e.g. if it declares prototype of `void foo(bool)` (or `struct { bool x; }`) your definitions silently change it to be `void foo(int)` (or `struct { int x; }`) which will force compiler to generate different assembly which will be incompatible with what library expects (yes, I've seen bugs caused by this).

Comment: @yugr: I'm not sure how that can happen. The header that defines `void foo(bool)` has to include, directly or indirectly, whatever header defines `bool`. If `typedef int bool;` occurs before that header is included, the definitions will conflict and be caught at compile time. If `typedef int bool;` occurs after that header, the header will still refer to the correct definition of `bool`. A `#define` could cause problems, but I didn't suggest that. In fact, if you look at the edit history (from 7 years ago), `typedef int bool;` wasn't even my suggestion.

Comment: I'm not sure why my name is in the answer. I'll edit it out.

Comment: @KeithThompson "The header that defines ... has to include" - only in ideal world. In practice many headers omit `stdbool.h` (see e.g. [this ncurses header](http://web.mit.edu/freebsd/head/contrib/ncurses/include/term_entry.h)) which users often "fix" with `typedef bool`, only to run into runtime bugs later.

Comment: @KeithThompson "typedef wasn't even my suggestion" - ah, ok.

Comment: @yugr: `/usr/include/curses.h` on my system (Ubuntu) has a comment discussing how it deals with `bool`. (The comment is incorrect; `<stdbool.h>` can't define `bool` as an enum.) Code that uses curses correctly shouldn't need to define its own `bool`. If curses is configured correctly, it uses `<stdbool.h>`. Experiment shows that it does so even if I `typedef` or `#define` `bool` before including `<curses.h>`.

Answer (score 6):

Just add the following:

```
#define __USE_C99_MATH

#include <stdbool.h>
```

Comment: What is `__USE_C99_MATH`?

Answer (score 5):

Somewhere in your code there is a line `#include <string>`. This by itself tells you that the program is written in C++. So using `g++` is better than `gcc`.

For the missing library: you should look around in the file system if you can find a file called `libl.so`. Use the `locate` command, try `/usr/lib`, `/usr/local/lib`, `/opt/flex/lib`, or use the brute-force `find / | grep /libl`.

Once you have found the file, you have to add the directory to the compiler command line, for example:

```
g++ -o scan lex.yy.c -L/opt/flex/lib -ll
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the `#include <stdbool.h>` was not enough.
The solution was to set `Intelli Sense Mode` to `gcc-x64` in the C/C++ Extension Settings.