# How to check using isdigit() if there more than one character

Tags: c++

So, I'm still new on coding, and my friend is kindly taught me a lot and I want to be learn it quick, then he gave me this exercise to study in my home
He gave me this question about booking table number, so I tried to make it..
But I'm having trouble with this part checking the table number if it is a digit or not... I was searching on google on how, but they only give example on how to do it with single character.. So, I made an account then ask here xD
btw, the table max number is 25.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

bool checkDigit(char tablenum){
    char digit[3];
    int n;
    int value = tablenum;
    if(tablenum>0 && tablenum<10)
        n=1;
    if(tablenum>9 && tablenum < 26)
        n=2;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        digit[i] = value%10;
        value /= 10;
    }
    if(n==1){
        printf("digit 0 = %d\nisdigit = %d\n",tablenum,isdigit(tablenum)); //just checking the isdigit value
        if(isdigit(digit[0])!=0){
            puts("It's digit");
            return true;
        }
        else{
            puts("It's not digit");
            return false;
        }
    }
    if(n==2){
        printf("digit 0 =  %d isdigit 0 = %d \ndigit 1 = %d isdigit 1 = %d\n",digit[0],isdigit(digit[0]),digit[1],isdigit(digit[1])); //checking the values too
        if(isdigit(digit[0]) != 0 && isdigit(digit[1]) != 0){
            puts("It's digits!");
            return true;
        }
        else{
            puts("It's not digits!");
            return false;
        }
    }
    else{
    printf("It's not digit!")
    return false;
    }
}

int main(){
    int num;
    bool itsdigit;
    do{
    scanf("%d",&num);fflush(stdin);

    itsdigit = checkDigit(num);

    }   while(itsdigit != 1 );
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Input = "25" "1" "0" "test"

Output = "It's a digit" "It's a digit" "It's not a digit" "

Since the table is only 1 to 25

When I input "1" on it shows the right digit, but when it when in to isdigit() I keep getting 0.

I wonder what when wrong with this, and please give explanation.
And thanks before!

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you really should not call `fflush` with an input stream like `stdin`. It's explicitly marked as *undefined behavior* in the C specification.

Comment: This code looks terribly complicated.

Comment: I think you should start with some simpler problems first.

Comment: That's not C or it is not complete. If you compile as C++, change the tag!

Comment: `num` is an `int` (a number), therefore it cannot possibly contain `"test"`. You need to read a _string_ but that's another story at your level....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
bool IsOnlyDigits(const char text[])
{
  int length = strlen(text);

  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    if (!isdigit(text[i]))
      return false;
  }

  return true;
}


int main() {
  char num[50];

  scanf("%s", num);

  if (IsOnlyDigits(num))
    puts("It's digits!");
  else
    puts("It's not digits!");

  fflush(stdout);
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

**Disclaimer:** non error checking and non bounds checking code. `#include`s omitted for brevity. Is has been tested under Visual Studio 2015 and seems to be working fine here.

Examples of input and output:

```
123
It's digits!

12a
It's not digits!

abc
It's not digits!
```

To understand this, you need to learn about strings and arrays. Just read the corrsponding chapters in your C textbook.

Comment: thanks for replying, sorry for being a messed up.. anyway when i input any numbers to your code it suddenly stopped working..

Comment: _"stopped working"_ what do you mean ? Did you get any error message ? What _exactly_ is your input ?

Comment: I just changed the end of the program (added `fflush(stdout);` right before `getchar();`). Try if this works better.

Comment: the .exe file crashed, when I input "1" "12" or "123", and the new answ still same condition

Comment: Crashed with what message ?? What IDE, programming environnment, operating system do you use ? Are you sure you execute the program in the answer ?

Comment: What IDE, programming environnment, operating system do you use ?

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio ?

Comment: I'm using Dev C++ and I don't have Visual Studio, my friend told me to study using Dev C++ since it's much simple for newbies(he said so). I use Windows 8.1

Comment: Run it with the debugger, when it stops working with the debugger, it will show you where exactly the problem happened. I can't tell you more about the debugger, I don't use Dev C++, but googling "dev c++ debugger" should help.

Comment: thanks very much, it took me a while to learn about the debugger but it's what i'm looking for, i also know how to use debugger now.. thanks bro!

Comment: @IrfandyJip so did you find out why the program stopped working, because here it works fine.

Comment: this might sound dumb, I didn't know there is #include<stdbool.h> so the compiler had the error i was talking about.. also I just declared int i outside the loop it also causes the error in Dev C++.. I got the ref here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133074/error-unknown-type-name-bool) and here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24881/how-do-i-fix-for-loop-initial-declaration-used-outside-c99-mode-gcc-error)

Comment: @IrfandyJip OK, "stopped working" assumes that your program has been compiled before. If you get compiler errors, your program won't run and therefore cannot "stop".

Answer (score 2):

You have *multiple* problems.

Lets start by taking a closer look at these two lines:

```
checkDigit(num);
itsdigit = checkDigit;
```

The first line *calls* `checkDigit` but throws away the result.

The second line does *not* call the function, instead the compiler will let it decay to a *pointer* to the function and assign that pointer to `itsdigit`. Your compiler should have complained about it.

Furthermore, [`isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit) doesn't *have* to return `1` when the character is a digit, it only have to return something which is non-zero.

Lastly, in the `digits` array you don't store *characters*, you store integer values. `isdigit(1)` will be false while `isdigit('1')` will be true. Just because you use the type `char` doesn't automatically store characters in the variables. And considering that you read an integer, and store its digits in the `digits` array, there's no need to check if the digits are actually digits. Of course the digits will be digits.

Comment: fixed it, changed the if, and itsdigit = checkDigit(num);
But still get the same result

Comment: I don't understand this part `Lastly, in the digits array you don't store characters, you store integer values. isdigit(1) will be false while isdigit('1') will be true. Just because you use the type char doesn't automatically store characters in the variables. And considering that you read an integer, and store its digits in the digits array, there's no need to check if the digits are actually digits. Of course the digits will be digits.` I actually know that i have this problem, the problem is how do i make it like isdigit('digit[0]') or something like that..

Comment: @IrfandyJip I'm also telling you that you don't *need* `isdigit`. The values stored in the `digits` array *are* the digits from the number you read. If you input `15` as the number, then `digits[0]` will be the *number* `5` and `digits[1]` will be the *number* `1`. They are numbers and not characters, and as single-digit numbers you don't need to make sure they are digits. You are all the time dealing with *numbers* and not strings of characters. At least until you want to check if the numbers are digits (which of course the single digits will be).

Answer (score 0):

You could instead create an array of type char or int, iterate through the array and check if any character instance is a digit or not using the isdigit() function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char arr[10];
  cin>>arr;
  for(int i=0;i<strlen(arr);i++){
    if(isdigit(arr[i])){
        cout<<arr[i]<<" is a digit\n";
    }
    else {
        cout<<arr[i]<<" is not a digit\n";
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: bro, sorry about the tags I thought I was the one who's wrong about the tags, it turns out I'm right.. Thanks for trying to answer!

Comment: No problem, turns out my answer is exactly the same as the person that got it right, wondering why I didn't notice.