# Tic Tac Toe game

Tags: c, tic-tac-toe

I was working on learning c code and was making a tic-tac-toe game. The Boolean issue was fixed. Now the issue is that it is looping the  printf("There is no empty space!"); and prinf("Invalid !!!"); after it take the player1 name. I also wanted to know if the line where I printed the array with the grid is correct or not.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>

char space[3][3] = {
    {'1', '2', '3'},
    {'4', '5', '6'},
    {'7', '8', '9'},
};
int row;
int column;
char token = 'x';
bool tie = false;
char n1[256];
char n2[256];

void functionboard()
{
    char space[3][3] = {
        {'1', '2', '3'},
        {'4', '5', '6'},
        {'7', '8', '9'},
    };

    printf("        |        |    \n");
    printf("  ", space[0][0], "| ", space[0][1], "| ", space[0][2], "  \n");
    printf("______|________|_____\n");
    printf("        |        |    \n");
    printf("  ", space[1][0], "  | ", space[1][1], "  | ", space[1][2], "  \n");
    printf("______|________|_____\n");
    printf("        |        |    \n");
    printf("  ", space[2][0], "  | ", space[2][1], "  | ", space[2][2], "  \n");
    printf("      |        |    \n");
}

void functionOne()
{

    int dight;

    if (token == 'x')
    {
        printf(n1, "please enter");
        scanf("&d", &dight);
    }

    if (token == '0')
    {
        printf(n2, "please enter");
        scanf("&d", &dight);
    }

    if (dight == 1)
    {
        row = 0;
        column = 0;
    }

    if (dight == 2)
    {
        row = 0;
        column = 1;
    }

    if (dight == 3)
    {
        row = 0;
        column = 2;
    }

    if (dight == 4)
    {
        row = 1;
        column = 0;
    }

    if (dight == 5)
    {
        row = 1;
        column = 1;
    }

    if (dight == 6)
    {
        row = 1;
        column = 2;
    }
    if (dight == 7)
    {
        row = 2;
        column = 0;
    }

    if (dight == 8)
    {
        row = 2;
        column = 1;
    }

    if (dight == 9)
    {
        row = 2;
        column = 2;
    }

    else if (dight < 1 || dight > 9)
    {
        prinf("Invalid !!!");
    }

    if (token == 'x' && space[row][column] != 'x' && space[row][column] != '0')
    {
        space[row][column] = 'x';
        token = '0';
    }

    else if (token == '0' && space[row][column] != 'x' && space[row][column] != '0')
    {
        space[row][column] = '0';
        token = 'x';
    }
    else
    {
        printf("There is no empty space!");
        functionboard();
    }
    functionOne();
}

bool functionDraw()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (space[i][0] == space[i][1] && space[i][0] == space[i][2] || space[0][i] == space[1][i] && space[0][i] == space[2][i])
            return true;
    }
    if (space[0][0] == space[1][1] && space[1][1] == space[2][2] || space[0][2] == space[1][1] && space[1][1] == space[2][0])
    {
        return true;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            if (space[i][j] != 'x' && space[i][j] != '0')
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    tie = true;
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    printf("Enter the name of the first player : \n");
    scanf("%c", n1);
    printf("Enter the name of the second player : \n");
    scanf("%c", n2);
    printf("%c is player1 so he/she will play first \n", n1);
    printf("%c is player2 so he/she will play first \n", n2);

    while (!functionDraw())
    {
        functionboard();
        functionOne();
        functionDraw();
    }

    if (token == 'x' && tie == false)
    {
        printf("%c Wins!!\n", n2);
    }
    else if (token == '0' && tie == false)
    {
        printf("%c Wins!!\n", n1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("its a draw!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: We need some more details, can you post the exact error and line number? And maybe only the snippet of code where it happens along with relevant variable declarations.

Comment: maybe not your current problem but definitely one of the next: There are two `space` arrays one global and one inside `functionboard`. The simple way to avoid such confusion is to not use globals at all. Then at least you'd get a compiler error like now, you just need to read it, or post it here if others should help with it

Comment: I believe you need to add: `#include <stdbool.h>`. Refer to [Use of bool in C](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bool-in-c/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the error you're getting is about the type `bool` and not the variable itself, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133074/error-unknown-type-name-bool): you need to also include `<stdbool.h>` to be able to use the `bool` type.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now i am having an issue where it is  looping printf("There is no empty space!"); and  player2 name printf("Invalid !!!").

Comment: I suggest you use a debugger on the application step by step, look at the conditions in your if checks, etc, and find out why it is looping. StackOverflow questions should be about a specific problem or error, not helping people debug their software. For example, in your case, the first question should have been similar to "error: unknown type bool", and then a second separate question "why is my loop condition not changing". After the original problem is solved, please ask a new question. Guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in `bool` type in classic C. You can use it though by using `#include <stdbool.h>`. The other solution is replacing it with an `int` since it can be used like a `bool`

Comment: If by "classic" C you mean either K&R C or C as it was before the C99 standard, there was no standard boolean type. But also no `<stdbool.h>` header. The C99 standard added the native type `_Bool` and the `<stdbool.h>` header (which add the `bool` type-alias).